# Does regex lookahead affect subsequent match?

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

I was playing around with regular expression look-aheads and came across something I don't understand.

I would expect this regular expression:

```
(?=1)x
```

to match this string:

```
"x1"
```

But it doesn't. In ruby the code looks like:

```
> "x1".match /(?=1)x/
=> nil
```

Here's what I would expect to happen:

1. We start with the regular expression parser's cursor on "x".
2. The regexp engine searches the string for "1" and gets a match. The cursor is still on "x"
3. The regexp engine searches for "x" and finds it, since the cursor hasn't moved.
4. Success! Profit!

But I'm apparently mistaken, because it's not matching. Could someone please tell me where I've gone wrong?

Incidentally, I've noticed that if the pattern matched by the lookahead contains the characters I'm matching in the subsequent expression, it works. ie. `(?=x)x` matches `x1` just fine. I suspect this is the key to the mystery, but I'm just not getting it. :)

Comment: its a common misconception that the regex lookarounds consume the string/moves the cursor. instead, think of lookarounds as a probe or a separate cursor moving forward before the real matcher cursor does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A look-ahead does not move the regex index forward, it "stands its ground", but it requires presence or absence of some pattern after the current position in string.

When you use `(?=1)x`, you tell the regex engine:

1. The next character must be `1`
2. Right at this position, match the character `x`.

It means you require `x` to be `1` which is never true/is always false. This regex will never match anything.

Here is another example from [regular-expressions.com](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

> Let's apply `q(?=u)i` to `quit`. The lookahead is now positive and is followed by another token. Again, `q` matches `q` and `u` matches `u`. Again, the match from the lookahead must be discarded, so the engine steps back from `i` in the string to `u`. The lookahead was successful, so the engine continues with `i`. But `i` cannot match `u`. So this match attempt fails. All remaining attempts fail as well, because there are no more `q`'s in the string.

Another must-read resource is [*Lookarounds Stand their Ground* at rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#stand_their_ground):

> Lookahead and lookbehind don't mean *look way ahead into the distance*. They mean ***look at the text immediately to the left or to the right***. If you want to inspect a piece of string further down, you will need to insert "binoculars" inside the lookahead to get you to the part of the string you want to inspect—for instance a `.*`, or, ideally, more specific tokens.

And

> Do not expect the pattern `A(?=5)` to match the `A` in the string `AB25`. Many beginners assume that the lookahead says that "there is a `5` somewhere to the right", but that is not so. After the engine matches the `A`, the lookahead `(?=5)` asserts that at the current position in the string, what immediately follows is a `5`. If you want to check if there is a `5` somewhere (anywhere) to the right, you can use `(?=[^5]*5)`.

Comment: `don't mean look way ahead into the distance`, but `(?=.*x)` does.

Comment: *You will need to insert "binoculars" inside the lookahead to get you to the part of the string you want to inspect—for instance a `.*`, or, ideally, more specific tokens.*

Comment: I have a strange belief that `.*` something, shifts the pointer to the end of the string right away to start its backtracking trek. And, inside assertions, the context is just another stack frame of normal regex.

Comment: Thanks! My mistake was in thinking that the lookahead would scan the entire string by default.

Comment: Howdy @StarrHorne , there are only a few defaults in regex, certainly assertions are not one of them. Most people ask what _language_ they need a particular regex. But that is not a good question, unless the engine they use is non-standard, or of old/modern flavors. Assertions are standard across most all engines. There is no particular rules on assertions, other than backtracking cannot escape its boundaries. This means you CAN scan the entire string, forward/backwards, depending on the contents of the assertion. Assertions are _separate, self-contained code_ existing between characters.

Comment: @StarrHorne: Actually, I should perhaps add a note about a regex that only consists of a look-ahead. Different regex implementations handle that differently. JavaScript would enter an infinite loop if you do not move the index "manually" inside *while*. Most language however perform the check before each symbol in the input string. After checking at the beginning, the regex engine goes on to the next symbol, and runs the look-ahead check from there. Have a look at [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/aJ4wJ7/1), where each letter is captured with a group in a look-ahead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to give you a long dissertation about regular expression assertions.

But I will tell you how to never confuse what they are, nor ever forget how to use them.

Regular expressions are processed (parsed) left to right.
They are nothing more than a fancy template.

`ASSERTIONS exist BETWEEN characters` in the target text, just like they exist
between expressions in the regular expression.

`They don't exist AT characters`, but between them.

That means you could easily look left or right and apply an appropriate
assertion, i.e. lookAHEAD or lookBEHIND.

That's all you really need to know to get started.

---

Your regex `(?=1)x` for example:

The regex says *at a position between characters* look ahead for a `1`,
if it looked and found a 1, continue with the next expression.
The next expression is looking for a literal `x`.

Now, if the next character is `1`, then its not `x`.
Result is, the regex bomb's, it can never match anything.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!