# Why does MATLAB's regexp only return first match token string?

Tags: regex, matlab

Suppose that we have this code in MATLAB:

```
ax = 'aa+bb+cc+dd';
middle_part = regexp(ax, '\+(\w+)\+','tokens');
```

Why does MATLAB only return `'bb'` as output, and not `'bb'` and `'cc'`?

Comment: Because you consume the trailing `+`. Use a lookahead `'\+(\w+)(?=\+)'`

Comment: Because of overlapping match.

Comment: @stribizhev. Thank you for comment. Why this function only found first matched string in my code? Can you describe more in answer?

Comment: @user2991243: I added an expanded answer. Please follow the link to my answer about lookaheads, it will help you understand how they work better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place the second `+` into a lookahead so that it is not consumed by the regex engine. [Here is an answer of mine on how look-aheads work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355133/does-regex-lookahead-affect-subsequent-match/33355260#33355260).

Here is code snippet:

```
ax = 'aa+bb+cc+dd';
middle_part = regexp(ax, '\+(\w+)(?=\+)','tokens');
disp(middle_part)
```

Result:

```
{                                                                                                                                                                   
  [1,1] =                                                                                                                                                           
  {                                                                                                                                                                 
    [1,1] = bb                                                                                                                                                      
  }                                                                                                                                                                 
  [1,2] =                                                                                                                                                           
  {                                                                                                                                                                 
    [1,1] = cc                                                                                                                                                      
  }                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

So, in short, here is what is going on: `\+(\w+)\+` matches `+bb+`, and moves the index right after the `+` that is after `bb`. So, there is only `cc+dd` to be tested. No match is found as the pattern requires 2 `+` symbols around 1 or more word characters.

With a lookahead version, `\+(\w+)(?=\+)`, the engine matches `+bb` that is right in front of a `+` and moves the index right after the second `b`. The string left is `+cc+dd`. So, there is another `+cc` match.

Comment: Great info here and in the linked post, thanks for sharing!