# Confusion in two Regex expressions to check at least one number

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using Regex to match passwords that are greater than 5 characters long and have two consecutive digits in JavaScript.

I tried it two different methods using lookahead, the first method returns false, whereas the second one returns true.

Here is the code:

```js
let sampleWord = "abc123";
let pwRegex = /(?=\w{5,})(?=\d{2,})/; //returns false
let result = pwRegex.test(sampleWord);
console.log(result);
```

```js
let sampleWord = "abc123";
let pwRegex = /(?=\w{5,})(?=\D*\d{2,})/; //returns true
let result = pwRegex.test(sampleWord);
console.log(result);
```

The only difference is that the second one also has `\D*`. As far as I know, it checks for non-numeric values occurring 0 or more times. But why is it required in this case?

<sub>P.S. This is a part of a challenge at [FreeCodeCamp.org](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/regular-expressions/positive-and-negative-lookahead) for learning Regular Expressions</sub>

Comment: Consecutive lookaheads are executed at the same location in the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Okay, but why do we need to check using `\D*` here? Won't just checking for at least two occurances of numeric characters using `\d{2,}` be enough?

Comment: `\D*` is not checking anything, it matches 0 or more chars other than digits *to get* to the digits that you want to match with`\d{2,}`. Note that the second one matches also due to the fact that `\w` also match digits as `\d` does, or neither would have worked.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ohkay. That makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33355260/3832970) of mine where I explained how lookaheads work. The last sentences actually explain that `\D*` (`[^\d]*`) thing. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51876308/strange-js-regex-lookahed), a pattern is discussed that follows the same logic as  your regex does.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot! It helped. And maybe you could mark this question as a duplicate of that question instead of the one you have marked at present?

Comment: I have changed the duplicate reason.